# How to prevent master page postback when update panel asynchronous postback happened

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel, postback, master-pages

When an asynchronous postback happened inside update panel, another postback happens also for MasterPage not only update panel embedded page .

I want to prevent this MasterPage postback .

is this possible ?

think like i have a MasterPage

and another page which is test.aspx which is content page of MasterPage

i have update panel at test.aspx

when asynchronous postback happens at this test.aspx update panel it also loads MasterPage Page_Load

i want to prevent this (it should not also load MasterPage Page_Load)

Thank you

Comment: Dump the update panels and go with JQuery. You will have much more control over what is sent back to the server.

Comment: OK, if you don't want to drop Update panels, check out this SO Question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388493/master-pages-and-postback-in-asp-net
The responses explain update panels and mater pages

Comment: bzarah nobody understood what asker asked at that topic "What I think question here is about: the asker want to post only the content page and not the master page. Not sure though. But I would like to know how to do that."

Comment: i asked at asp.net forums too
it was not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET's UpdatePanel (as well as any normal asp.net page)'s postback does postback the master page as well.

Normally, to properly deal with postbacks, programmers check for it and program accordingly :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dataBindAndSetUpControls();
    }
 }
```

So, my answer here is that I don't know if it is possible (and if it is, it certainly isn't easy), and that your request is not a normal thing to do, and programmers handle PostBacks via the blurb above.